# How to change URL of item in Wordpress dashboard in order to go directly to first post inside it

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created some custom fields for the Wordpress dashboard, for example:

**functions.php**

```
 function create_field() {

   register_post_type('field',
       array(
           'labels' => array(
               'name' => 'Field',
               'singular_name' => 'Field'
           ),
           'public' => true,
           'has_archive' => false,
           'rewrite' => false,
           'show_in_menu' => false,

           'capability_type' => 'post',
           'capabilities' => array(
               'create_posts' => false
           ),
           'map_meta_cap' => true,
         )
      );
   }

   add_action('init', 'create_field');
```

In some of them, only one post will be created. It will be continually edited and never deleted. So, what I want is to change de URL of this item in dashboard menu and go directly to this post inside it instead of showing the list of posts, because it will be no necessary.

For example, in the dashboard menu, when click in Products, instead of going to `www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=products`, I want it to go directly to the only post created inside it: `www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=24&action=edit`.

Is that possible? I searched and tried a lot of things, since `rewrite`, different `add_action` functions, removing the item and trying to replace it and so on. I don't know exactly what else I can try for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a little more without success. Unfortunately I had to use JavaScript, something I was avoiding, but solves it temporarily.

First, I used `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook in **functions.php** to add JavaScript on the administration screens.

```
function admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( "", get_template_directory_uri() . "/scripts_admin.js", "", "", true );
}
add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", "admin_scripts" );
```

Then on my JavaScript I replaced the link hrefs:

```
// examples
document.querySelector("#menu-posts-products a").href = "post.php?post=10&action=edit";
document.querySelector("#menu-posts-contact a").href = "post.php?post=20&action=edit";
```

I still think there is a way to do it through Wordpress, maybe in the creation of `Post Types`. But for now, that solves it.